# index.js:72 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Account does not exist BoFCbRsR9PYZTUx7KVbJ2UfpbPyCv6qZ2sjHzf4ouoQb

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, pda

**The front end is below**

> const newVideo = async () => {
> console.log("New Video Module")
> //const wallet = useWallet()
> let [state_pda] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
> [utf8.encode('state'), wallet.publicKey.toBuffer()],
> program.programId,
> )
> console.log(state_pda is , ${state_pda.toString()});

```
const stateInfo = await program.account.stateAccount.fetch(state_pda);
console.log("stateInfo is ", stateInfo);

let [video_pda] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [utf8.encode('video'), stateInfo.videoCount.toArrayLike(Buffer, 'be', 8)],
  program.programId,
);
```

**The smart contract is**

```
/// CreateState context
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateState<'info> {
    // Authenticating state account
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"state".as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = size_of::<StateAccount>() + 8
    )]
    pub state: Account<'info, StateAccount>,

    // Authority (this is signer who paid transaction fee)
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    /// System program
    /// CHECK: Simple test account for tiktok
    pub system_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    // Token program
    #[account(constraint = token_program.key == &token::ID)]
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}

/// CreateVideo context
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateVideo<'info> {
    // Authenticate state account
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"state".as_ref()], bump)]
    pub state: Account<'info, StateAccount>,

    // Authenticate video account
    #[account(
        init,
        // Video account use string "video" and index of video as seeds
        seeds = [b"video".as_ref(), state.video_count.to_be_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = size_of::<VideoAccount>() + TEXT_LENGTH + USER_NAME_LENGTH + USER_URL_LENGTH+VIDEO_URL_LENGTH+8+32*NUMBER_OF_ALLOWED_LIKES_SPACE // 32 bits in a pubkey and we have 5
    )]
    pub video: Account<'info, VideoAccount>,

    // Authority (this is signer who paid transaction fee)
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    /// System program
    /// CHECK: Simple test account for tiktok
    pub system_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    // Token program
    #[account(constraint = token_program.key == &token::ID)]
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    // Clock to save time
    pub clock: Sysvar<'info, Clock>,
}
```

Comment: Can someone help out with the solution?

Answer (score 3):

You’re including wallet in the PDA of state on the front end, but the seeds on the smart contract don’t include wallet. Also I’d use `Buffer.from(x, “utf8”)` instead of utf8.encode.

Comment: Which line of code above will these changes be effected? Be more explicit Please.

Comment: seeds = [b"state".as_ref()],

Should include wallet